# Sharing Files from Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) using SMB (Samba)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, file-sharing, samba

I enabled file sharing and in options SNB sharing on my Mac but still none of the computers in my local area network can reach it. They can ping the computer and can ssh but only sharing doesn't work. any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried only via IP instead of the name? eg. \\192.168.1.50

Comment: yes. i tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalling apple snow resolved the issue.
thanks for all of your support.

Answer (score 2):

*Just a noob check, but did you select the account you want to share in the SMB prefs?*

Have you tried changing the NetBIOS Name and Workgroup in the network settings? I find that I often have to set these before my "new macs" will show up on windows PCs.

To do this visit "Network" in system preferences, then select your primary/active network adapter and then click "Advanced..".

[image: Network Prefs]

Inside this click the WINS tab. Should look something like this:

[image: WINS Tab]

Set your computer name and the workgroup you want the mac to be part of here.

Comment: thanks for your advice but unfortunately it did not do any good. when i try to mount from my linux box i get the error 'Host is down'.

Comment: How odd. Have you double checked the config on your linux box?

Comment: +1; it is unbelievable that SMB settings like these are hidden far away from the regular SMB settings.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me: **insert the password in CAPITALS!** Special chars and numbers as usual.

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting a connectivity issue, take it from the ground up.

1. Can you ping it by IP address alone?
2. Can you ping the device by name?  If not, but you can ping it by IP address, as mentioned above, then you either have an /etc/hosts file that is giving conflicting information, or you have a DNS problem.
3. If you can successfully ping the device by IP and name, check the Samba basics in the smb.config file.
4. WINS setup?  Netbios name set? Firewall down*

*It's always a good idea to drop the firewall when troubleshooting issues like these.  Then, when you've got it working, bring the firewall back up and work with it to open up the appropriate port(s) needed.  If it will work with the firewall down, but not when it's up, then it's a firewall configuration issue.

I truly hope some of this helps ... 
(please forgive me if it's common knowledge to you - you just never know how much somebody does know)